# Why does my SQL query give me a different table than I'd expect?

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't get what I am doing wrong here...

> Write a query below that retrieves the chamber and the maximum tonnage
>   for each distinct value of chamber as the column max_tonnage from the
>   voyages table grouped by chamber.

**This is my SQL query:**

```
SELECT chamber, MAX(tonnage), COUNT() AS max_tonnage
FROM voyages
GROUP BY chamber
```

It gives me this table:

```
#   chamber MAX(tonnage)    max_tonnage
1   A        1150           49
2   D        880             5
```

I need to get this table:

```
#   chamber max_tonnage
1   A         1150
2   D         880
```

What I don't understand is... how can it show MAX(tonnage) as a column? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Then just remove `COUNT() AS max_tonnage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what your query asks it to do.

Try this

```
SELECT chamber, MAX(tonnage) AS max_tonnage FROM voyages GROUP BY chamber
```

Comment: But what does COUNT() do then?

Comment: Refer to some SQL tutorials. You'll learn a lot. Count here will give you total number of rows for each chamber.

Answer (score 1):

You have an unnecessary COUNT() in the code. Try

`SELECT chamber, MAX(tonnage) AS max_tonnage FROM voyages GROUP BY chamber`

Answer (score 0):

You wanted results are two columns, but the select clause of yours return three.
Try this:

SELECT chamber, MAX(tonnage) AS max_tonnage FROM voyages GROUP BY chamber

Answer (score -1):

Assuming `#` is the `rowid`, you are asking for 3 columns back :

```
1 chamber
2 MAX(tonnage)
3 COUNT() AS max_tonnage
```

-> Remove 3